# Burninate, merge or retag [aws-sdk-v2]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

[aws-sdk-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-v2) has 75 questions tagged and the following tag description:

> Questions pertaining to V2 of the AWS SDK

But... v2 of which AWS SDK? There are [11 official AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk), and each of them are maintained version-independent of one-another.  Some are not yet on v2, while others are on v3. "aws-sdk-v2" is a meaningless aggregation by itself, without further specifying which SDK is being used.  I can see the reason for having a "aws-sdk" tag (the SDKs themselves are just a language-specific abstraction of the AWS API) but "aws-sdk-v2" just isn't meaningful in that same way.

I think [aws-sdk-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-v2) should be burninated (or just merged with aws-sdk?), with the questions retagged to include at least:

- the appropriate language tag
- [aws-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk), if it is not already present

---

**Update following discussion:** With no other comments, it seems the simplest way forward to merge these tags is a tag synonym. This will require moderator intervention; when I try, I am getting an error: `Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators`.

Can a moderator that reads this post apply aws-sdk-v2 as a tag synonym of aws-sdk, please?

Comment: Or at least retagged.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Agree, that would be fine too.

Comment: Although I don't know anything about AWS, it looks to me (as usual) that merging would be the most appropriate course of action here. I can't see a compelling justification for a bunch of manual retagging, nor its other undesirable effects, and the "burnination" meme has outlived its usefulness as people increasingly abuse it to mean "clean up".

Comment: @CodyGray I likewise don't know much about meta terminology and would not like to get in an argument about the nuances of burnination in this thread. :) I simply want a useless tag to be removed and that seemed to be the most straightforward way to get the conversation started. Apologies for that. When you say 'merging', do you mean a tag synonym or is there some other mechanism for tag merging? I have enough points in aws-sdk to suggest a tag synonym and can go ahead with that if it is agreeable.

Comment: Hmm, seems I can't do that: `Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators`

Comment: I have manually removed this tag from 85 Questions (replaced by `aws-sdk`). The tag should be deleted overnight.