# Tag-synonym assistance for AWS-related tags

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

There are a few AWS-related [Stack Overflow tag synonym requests](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) that are pending votes.

Can I please invite assistance from people who know AWS in deciding a few of these tag synonyms, so they can be decided one way or the other?

- <s>[amazon-elb](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-elb/synonyms) <- elastic-load-balancer</s> Done
- [amazon-vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-vpc/synonyms) <- VPC
- <s>[amazon-cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-cloudwatch/synonyms) <- cloudwatch</s>  **DONE**
- <s>[amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-cloudformation/synonyms) <- cloudformation</s> Done

Also, I'm not sure how to do this, but:

- [elastic-beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/elastic-beanstalk/synonyms) <- beanstalk
- Both the above should actually be `aws-elastic-beanstalk` -- Should I create a new tag and propose some new synonyms?

Comment: VPC is not only the domain for amazon so I'm not sure if I agree with that suggestion.

Comment: Feel free to down-vote if the synonym is not correct.

Comment: Good idea but I need 5 rep first in that tag to be allowed to vote on it. Well played Sir, well played .. ;)

Comment: I've helped in the tags that I am able. Regarding rene's concerns about VPC, maybe we can make a note in the tag description to use [amazon-vpc] for AWS questions, instead of a synonym? @JohnRotenstein Could you check out the proposed tag synonyms in [aws-sdk] when you get a moment? Trying to consolidate disparate sdk-related tags. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338362/burninate-merge-or-retag-aws-sdk-v2

Comment: also aws-cloudfront for cloudfront

Comment: vpc seems wrong to merge into amazon-vpc - vpc is a general concept, not one specific to amazon. aws-elastic-beanstalk and elastic-beanstalk are synonyms of amason-elastic-beanstalk. VPC was downvoted away, but beyond that, this looks like it's [status-complete]