# Merge the 3 Amazon CloudFormation tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

There are three tags for cloudformation:

- [cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudformation)
- [aws-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudformation)
- [amazon-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudformation)

I think all three should be merged into [aws-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudformation), and perhaps made into synonyms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag-synonym assistance for AWS-related tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345497/tag-synonym-assistance-for-aws-related-tags) and also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341927/merge-cloudformation-into-amazon-cloudformation